Using Google Speech-to-Text gRPC google.cloud.speech.v1 on the frontend
I would like to know if it's even possible to use google.cloud.speech.v1 gRPC variant to transcribe a webRTC stream audio tracks.
currently I'm using the REST API to get results, but they are not great, because I'm recording 5 second clips and send them one by one to get the transcriptions.
I've tried importing the GoogleSpeech SDK on npm, although it seems that its only available in the node enviroment.
